# Iterating through grouped RDD Value in Python Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce

given this python list with following format: (userid, action, itemid, timestamp) and contents:

```
user_action_list = [('uid1', 'click', 'item1', 1454880986),
                    ('uid1', 'view', 'item1', 1454880984),
                    ('uid1', 'view', 'item2', 1454880984),
                    ('uid1', 'view', 'item3', 1454880984),
                    ('uid1', 'purchase', 'item1', 1454880994),
                    ('uid1', 'purchase', 'item4', 1454880994),
                    ('uid2', 'view', 'item1', 1454880985),
                    ('uid2', 'view', 'item2', 1454880985),
                    ('uid2', 'view', 'item5', 1454880985),
                    ('uid2', 'purchase', 'item2', 1454880995),
                    ('uid3', 'click', 'item5', 1454880985),
                    ('uid3', 'view', 'item6', 1454880985),
                    ('uid3', 'purchase', 'item5', 1454880995),
                    ('uid3', 'purchase', 'item6', 1454880995),
                    ('uid3', 'view', 'item6', 1454880999),
                    ('uid3', 'view', 'item5', 1454881010),
                    ('uid4', 'view', 'item1', 1454880910),
                    ('uid4', 'view', 'item2', 1454880910)]
```

I would like to use spark to return all items that directly precede any "purchase" action items. The format should be ((userid, itemid), (timestamp, action)); an example of a returned item is: (('uid1', 'item1'), (1454880986, 'click')). My question is: how can I can iterate through either the object or list that is returned from the groupByKey function?

```
result_rdd = user_action_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2], x[3]))) \
                                .groupByKey() \
                                .mapValues(lambda x: list(x)) \

return result_rdd.collect()
```

My thought is that I should be iterating through the rdd values and returning an item that precedes a 'purchase' condition. Is this correct or possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are more efficient ways to handle (although `groupByKey` is unlikely a one) but probably the simplest approach is to use window functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lead

df = (sc.parallelize(user_action_list)
    .toDF(["userid", "action", "itemid", "timestamp"]))

w = Window().partitionBy("userid").orderBy("timestamp")

(df
    .withColumn("ind", lead("action", 1).over(w))
    .where(col("ind") == "purchase")
    .drop("ind")
    .show())

## +------+--------+------+----------+
## |userid|  action|itemid| timestamp|
## +------+--------+------+----------+
## |  uid1|   click| item1|1454880986|
## |  uid1|purchase| item1|1454880994|
## |  uid2|    view| item5|1454880985|
## |  uid3|    view| item6|1454880985|
## |  uid3|purchase| item5|1454880995|
## +------+--------+------+----------+
```

Regarding iteration over grouped values in RDD you can simply pass an arbitrary function instead of `lambda x: list(x)`.